# DatingApp programming: ActiveRecord association for finding Users where there are no Approvals or one 1 way approvals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm building a dating-style app where `User`s can approve other users.
I use an `Approval` model to track these relationships. Each `Approval` has a `user_id` and an `approved_id` -- the User id of the approved `User`. It also has `rejected_at`, a datetime for indicating one `User` has rejected another.

To present eligible Users to the `current_user`, I must query for Users for which there are either

- No `Approval` relationship
- `Approval` relationship only with the `approved_id` as the `current_user.id` (meaning the eligible User approves the current_user but there's no relationship the other way around
- Exclude `User`s that have an `Approval` with a non-nil `rejected_at` attribute where `approved_id` is the `User` or `user_id` is the `current_user`.

How can I craft an ActiveRecord query to find eligible Users? I understand I can do a `joins` on `Approval` but I also want to account for there being NO `Approval` relationship between `User`s! I'm thinking it may make more sense to just make 2 separate queries but I'd like to know if it's possible to combine into one..

Comment: Are you looking for a query which satisfies all three or either of three?

Comment: All 3 bult there is an XOR with the first & second. I believe that #1 & #2 is possible with an OR clause

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you want is a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html), which will include rows from `users` whether or not there are any matching rows in `approvals`. That way, you get either a `User` that has issued no `Approval` about your target `User`, or one who has and we can filter for rejection.

[The query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2df52/2) would look like

```sql
-- Looking for users who either have no opinion or have approved user 1
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN approvals
  ON users.id = approvals.user_id
  AND approvals.approved_id = 1 -- Filter for only approvals of user 1
WHERE users.id != 1 -- Ignore user 1
  AND (
    approvals.approved_id IS NULL -- Approving user has no opinion of user 1
    OR approvals.rejected_at IS NULL -- Approving user has not rejected user 1
  )
;
```

In pieces,

- `users LEFT OUTER JOIN approvals` considers all `users`, even if they have no `approvals`
- `ON users.id = approvals.user_id` pairs `users` with `approvals` they created
- `ON ... AND approvals.approved_id = 1` considers only `approvals` for `User 1`
- `WHERE users.id != 1` considers only other `users`
- `WHERE ... approvals.approved_id IS NULL` takes `users` that *have not* created any `approvals` pertaining to `User 1`.
- `WHERE ... approvals.rejected_at IS NULL` takes `users` that *did* create an `Approval` for `User 1`, and it was not a rejection

`ActiveRecord` doesn't do anything particularly pretty when we translate this, but it works:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def eligible_partners
    User.joins( # Join like we did before
      <<-SQL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN approvals
        ON  users.id = approvals.user_id
        AND approvals.approved_id = #{self.id}
      SQL
    ).where.not(id: id) # Ignore ourselves
     .where( # Filter for no approvals or a positive approval
       <<-SQL
         approvals.approved_id IS NULL
         OR approvals.rejected_at IS NULL
       SQL
     )
  end
end
```

If you want something more readable, you can gather up the IDs of every `User` that has rejected a given person, and then get all of the other `User`s. On one hand, it's two queries; on the other, it may be less expensive than a `JOIN` once your tables get big, and it's way easier to understand.

```ruby
  def other_eligible_partners
    rejecter_ids = Approval
      .where(approved_id: id) # About ourselves
      .where.not(rejected_at: nil) # Rejected us
      .pluck(:user_id)
    User.where.not(id: rejecter_ids + [id]) # People who didn't reject us
  end
```